# Jenkins integration with cloud foundary -ClosedChannelException

Tags: jenkins, proxy, cloud-foundry

When i connecting Jenkins to cloudfoundary behind proxy, getting exception as below:

[image]
can any one help on this?

Cloud Foundry Plugin:
channel stopped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:219)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1301)
    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushTask.perform(CloudFoundryPushTask.java:137)
    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushBuilder.perform(CloudFoundryPushBuilder.java:166)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at 
    hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:945)       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:896)        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
            at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:86)
            ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap] :
```

Comment: Please add the error message as text, don't post an image of it.

Comment: added exception  as text